# Dual boot issue: HDD and SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ssd

My computer contains a normal HDD hard drive and a SSD. The original HDD is Disk 0 and the new SSD is Disk 1. The windows OS is on Disk 1. Can I install Ubuntu on the HDD and Windows on the SSD? Can I get back and forth between the 2 OS? I am afraid after I install Ubuntu on the HDD the Grub menu won't come up since the 2 OS are on different hard drives. In a couple months I will not want linux anymore. Can I easily remove Linux and have my windows OS come back to normal? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear. But if you have Windows installed and running now, then yes you can install Ubuntu on another drive. When you install, you need to select the disk with Windows installed as the location for the boot files. Ubuntu will detect your Windows installation and then Ubuntu will install GRUB with a menu that allows you to select Ubuntu or Windows every time you boot.

If you haven't installed anything or want a clean install of Windows, then I would recommend you swap the locations of the drives so the SSD is the first one and the HDD is second. Then install Windows on the SSD like normal, then install Ubuntu and select the second drive for the OS /home partition but select /dev/sda as the location for the boot files. The rest will be like above with a menu.

Comment: You nailed my issue. I don't know how to swap the drives to make the SSD first and HDD second. Now when I try to install Ubuntu from my flashdrive it only sees the first disk which does not contain Windows, so it tells me I don't have an OS currently when I do. So Windows is not detected. It I go ahead and do the install with Ubuntu and Windows is not detected will the GRUB menu still appear?

Comment: Then a follow up question. Can I remove Ubuntu from my HDD when I am finished with it?

Comment: If you're using the "guided install" where the program tries to figure it out, Ubuntu will use the first physical drive in the system (/dev/sda) and ignore the others. If you can do manual or "something else" then it will find your drives and let you change how it installs. You may want to read some guides on how to install Ubuntu. But I'd rather you get the drives swapped around so the HDD is first, and the SSD is second in the system. Makes it easier to install with a basic system but Ubuntu is quite flexible.